# Regex Key Value from Text and Brackets

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm working on trying to parse text from a file into a Hash.  Regex just isn't my thing and I am trying to get a better understanding of how to do something like this.

```
-some-
key1=value1
key2=value2

key3=value3

; comment
-something-
key4=value4
key5=value5
```

The result should be something like this

```
some.key1 = value1
some.key2 = value2
some.key3 = value3
something.key4 = value4
something.key5 = value5
```

I'm working in Ruby and I am able to capture what in between the dashes but the double line breaks, and comments are throwing me off.  Currently I have something like this which finds what's in the dashes and puts it in group 1 and then stuffs the next line in group 2, but then stops there.

```
data = Hash[text.scan(/^\-(.*?)\-\s(.*?)$/m)]
```

Any help in understanding how this would work is greatly appreciated.

**Update: Figured a way to do it with two different Regex's and a loop.**

But there has to be a more efficient way, right?

```
data = Hash.new
Hash[text.scan(/\-(.*?)\-\s([^\r\n]*(?:[\r\n]+(?!\-).*)*)/)].each do |key, value|
    data[key] = Hash[value.scan(/(?<=\s|\A)([^\s=]+)\s*=\s*(.*?)(?=(?:\s[^\s=]+=|$))/m)]
end

puts data.inspect
```

Comment: You can post your solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
text = "-some-
key1=value1
key2=value2

key3=value3

; comment
-something-
key4=value4
key5=value5"

data = Hash[text.scan(/(\w+)=(\w+)/)]

puts data
```

Output:

```
{"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2", "key3"=>"value3", "key4"=>"value4", "key5"=>"value5"}
```

`(\w+)` will capture 1 or more alphanumeric symbols on either side of `=`, and we do not need a multiline mode option here unless you have special characters other than digits, letters and `_`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to pick up what is in between the dashes.